# Rails form nested attributes unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is throwing this error:

> Unpermitted parameter: :conversation

Does having `conversation_attributes` in `post_params` not permit `conversations`? What am I doing wrong?

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = @character.posts.create(post_params)
...

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit( conversation_attributes: [ missives_attributes: [ :content ] ] )
end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_one :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

**postconversation.rb**

```
has_many :missives, class_name: 'Postmissive', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :missives
```

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :conversation do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for :missives do |fff| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, character.callsign %>
    <%= fff.text_area :content %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Logs**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxHD...VoA==", "callsign"=>"baz", "post"=>{"conversation_attributes"=>{"missives_attributes"=>{"content"=>"Hello"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(conversation: [missives: [:content]])
end
```

Update:
Try to explicitly wrap it with hash:

```
params.require(:post).permit({ conversation: [{ missives: [:content]}] })
```

Comment: This results in this error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Postconversation expected, got {"missives"=>{"content"=>"Hello"}} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess):

Comment: try to explicitly wrap it with hash.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. It was necessary to use `f.fields_for :conversation_attributes`.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = @character.posts.create(post_params)
...

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit( conversation_attributes: [ missives_attributes: [ :content ] ] )
end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_one :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

**postconversation.rb**

```
belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :conversation
has_many :missives, class_name: 'Postmissive', dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'conversation_id', inverse_of: :conversation
accepts_nested_attributes_for :missives
```

**postmissive.rb**

```
belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', foreign_key: 'conversation_id', inverse_of: :missives
validates :conversation, presence: true # validates :conversation_id does not work
```

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :conversation_attributes do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for 'missives_attributes[]', Postmissive.new do |fff| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, character.callsign %>
    <%= fff.text_area :content %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Submitted Parameters**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxHD...VoA==", "callsign"=>"baz", "post"=>{"conversation_attributes"=>{"missives_attributes"=>[{"content"=>"Hello"}]}}}
```